# Pass command line args to a Docker debugging run of a .NET Core console application in Visual Studio Container Tools

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, .net-core, command-line-arguments

In Visual Studio 2019, I can debug a .NET Core console application with command line arguments using a configuration similar to below in `launchSettings.json`.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "MyConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "-a -v"
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to debug this using Visual Studio Container Tools inside of a Docker container. I added another build profile to `launchSettings.json` as follows:

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "commandLineArgs": "-a -v"
    },
    "MyConsoleApp": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "-a -v"
    }
  }
}
```

This successfully builds and runs the console application per the defined `Dockerfile`, however the `docker run` command does not include the values specified in `commandLineArgs` in the `Docker` profile of `launchSettings.json`.

The generated `docker run` command (notably without `-a -v`):

```
docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\MyUser\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "C:\Users\MyUser\source\repos\MyConsoleApp\src\MyConsoleApp:/app" -v "C:\Users\MyUser\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -v "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" --entrypoint tail myconsoleapp:dev -f /dev/null
```

**Question:**

How can I pass command line args to a Docker debugging run of a .NET Core console application in Visual Studio Container Tools?

**Update:**

Just stumbled on [this](https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/62).

When I add something like this to my project file:

```
<DockerDebuggeeArguments>-a -v</DockerDebuggeeArguments>
```

The console app fails to debug at all with the following message:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
You may only use the Microsoft .NET Core Debugger (vsdbg) with
Visual Studio Code, Visual Studio or Visual Studio for Mac software
to help you develop and test your applications.
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Did you mean to run dotnet SDK commands? Please install dotnet SDK from:
  https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=798306&clcid=0x409
The target process exited without raising a CoreCLR started event. Ensure that the target process is configured to use .NET Core. This may be expected if the target process did not run on .NET Core.
The program 'dotnet' has exited with code 145 (0x91).
```

I have `Microsoft .NET Core SDK 2.2.301 (x64)` installed.

If I exclude the `DockerDebuggeeArguments` value, I can debug in Docker, but no command line arguments are passed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the correct solution is adding the below line to the `.csproj` file:

`<DockerDebuggeeArguments>-a -v</DockerDebuggeeArguments>`

However, there is a bug right now that does not allow that to work.

Some workarounds for the moment:

> I've identified a bug in our code preventing this scenario from
>   working as intended. I've identified some possible workarounds:
>
> 1. If you're using Linux containers, try setting the following MSBuild
>      properties, to pass in `-a -v` to your application:
>
> `<DockerDebuggeeArguments>--additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2 --additionalProbingPath /root/.nuget/fallbackpackages "bin/$(Configuration)/$(TargetFramework)/$(AssemblyName).dll" -a -v</DockerDebuggeeArguments>`
>
> `<DockerDebuggeeProgram>/usr/bin/dotnet</DockerDebuggeeProgram>`
>
> 2. For Windows containers:
>
> `<DockerDebuggeeArguments>--additionalProbingPath
>   c:\.nuget\fallbackpackages2 --additionalProbingPath
>   c:\.nuget\fallbackpackages
>   "bin\$(Configuration)\$(TargetFramework)\$(AssemblyName).dll" -a
>   -v</DockerDebuggeeArguments>`
>
> `<DockerDebuggeeProgram>C:\Program Files\dotnet\dotnet</DockerDebuggeeProgram>`
>
> 3. For either Windows or
>      Linux containers, if it's an option, you can change your code to use
>      environment variables instead of command-line arguments

via [@bwateratmsft](https://github.com/microsoft/DockerTools/issues/62#issuecomment-511542428)